# How to calculate the touch location with convertToWorldSpace?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, coordinates

i would like to convert the touch location as a world coordinate in my tile game. With this code, i clicked on the right of the screen (so that my character walks in the tiled game, and the background goes slowly to the left) :

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
        CGPoint test = [self convertToWorldSpace:location];

        CCLOG(@"test : %.2g", test.x);
```

The `test` log gives me :

> 50, 72, 1e+02, 2.6e+02, 4.2e+02, (and then goes down) 3.2e+02, 9.5, -1.9e+02, etc.

Does anyone know why?
I would like to calculate the "real" coordinate of the touch, so that i know when the character has to keep going (**click on the right of its actual position**) or if he has to turn and go backwards. (**click on the left of its actual position**)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that you are doing with cocos2d, you do in single OpenGL view. So, if you handle touches by your scene or layer with the size of scene, it is enough to call these lines

```
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
```

to get touch position relatieve to your screen. `convertToWorldSpace` just translates local node coordinates to world coordinates

Comment: thanks, but this gives me a maximum value of 480 in the x-axis, so the reference is the screensize. When i use convertToWorldSpace, it goes to 480 then goes down in the negative values... i would like to have something like : 480, then 500, 630, 850 etc. if i keep on clicking on the right of my character's position, do you know how to do this?

Comment: then you need convert it not for world space, but to the space of your big view. smth like [myScrollableView convertToNodeSpace: location];

Answer (score 1):

Those numbers printed look fine, but you're using the `%g` format specifier, which according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) on the subject, does this:

> 64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in the style of %e if the exponent is less than –4 or greater than or equal to the precision, in the style of %f otherwise.

Unless that's what you want, you should probably use `%f` instead, which won't produce any numbers in scientific notation.

Comment: thanks Jake! `%f` is better indeed, for my issue, the code above gives me a maximum value of 480 in the x-axis, so the reference is the screensize. When i use convertToWorldSpace, it goes to 480 then goes down in the negative values... i would like to have something like : 480, then 500, 630, 850 etc. if i keep on clicking on the right of my character's position. Would you know how to do this?

Comment: @Paul To do that, you'll need to reference your main view (the one that actually scrolls), then do something like `[mainView convertToNodeSpace:location]`.